# How to get OpenSSH to use OCSP for revocation

Tags: ssh, certificate, ocsp

As the title says, is there any (free) library, patch, etc. that allows OpenSSH to be configured to check x.509 certificate revocation via OCSP (online certificate status protocol)? If so, can you please point me to documentation and/or a download page?

(And yes, I am asking about OpenSSH not OpenSSL.)

Thanks in advance.

[Note that I posted [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151964/how-to-get-openssh-to-use-ocsp-for-revocation), but no one answered so perhaps this is a better venue.]

Comment: Someone answered over in the Info Sec group:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69147/how-to-get-openssh-to-use-ocsp-for-revocation

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: The mentioned `security.stackexchange.com` [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69147/how-to-get-openssh-to-use-ocsp-for-revocation) no longer appears to be there.

OpenSSH, by default, uses passwords/passphrases, and public/private *keys* for authenticating clients, not the [*X.509 certificates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) that SSL/TLS uses.  And [OCSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) is a protocol for checking the status of *certificates*, not keys.  Thus the short answer is "No, there is no way to get OpenSSH to use OCSP for checking client keys."

Now, that said, there *is* a patch for OpenSSH [which adds support for X.509 certificates](http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/).  Once this patch is applied, your OpenSSH will be X.509 certificate aware, *and* can then use OCSP for checking the certificate status as desired.

Hope this helps!